# What is a Tulip Word™?

Tags: word-property

This puzzle is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **tulip** word.
Here is a list of examples:

| TULIP | NOT TULIP |
| --- | --- |
| tulip | rose |
| poppy | iris |
| chrysanthemum | orchid |
| baker | florist |
| priest | photographer |
| reception | service |
| expenses | debts |
| marriage | divorce |

And CSV version:

```
TULIP, NOT TULIP
tulip, rose
poppy, iris
chrysanthemum, orchid
baker, florist
priest, photographer
reception, service
expenses, debts
marriage, divorce
```

**QUESTION:** What is the rule to tell whether a word is a **tulip** word or not? Why is it called a **tulip** word?

Comment: Isn't "debts" a tulip word?

Comment: @VictorStafusa rot13(V qba'g guvax fb, orpnhfr gur O vf fvyrag, fb vg vf abg cebabhaprq, rira gubhtu vg rkvfgf. Cre gur pbeerpg nafjre, vg'f abg jurgure gur o, c, be z rkvfg, ohg engure orpnhfr gurl ner abg fcbxra.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A Tulip Word is

> A word with a [bilabial consonant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilabial_consonant), meaning that your Two Lips come together to form one of its consonant sounds (p, m, or b).

Comment: Spot on! Nice job not being thrown off by the presence of those letters in the "not tulip" category.

Comment: Isn't "debts" a tulip word?

Comment: @VictorStafusa No. To avoid spoiling the answer for others, paste this into [rot13](https://rot13.com) for the explanation: "Gur 'o' vf fvyrag va abezny, Nzrevpna Ratyvfu."